# Attempt to create a function in R where my input extracts value based on another column

Tags: r, function

I have a data frame which looks like this:

first 6 lines of the dataset :

[image]

I am trying to create a function whereby i can input Customer_ID and return Age, full name etc.

```
Customer_Reporting <- function(Customer_ID) {
  x <- customer_information$Age[customer_information$Customer_ID=="Customer_ID"]
  paste("Customer's age is",print(x))

}
```

However returns

```
> Customer_Reporting(1251)
numeric(0)
[1] "Customer's age is "
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Hi! instead of posting a picture, please add the output of `dput(head(customer_information))`

Comment: `x <- customer_information$Age[customer_information$Customer_ID==Customer_ID]` (without quotes) and then `paste("Customer's age is",x)` (without `print`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Customer_ID` is a variable use it without quotes and no need to use `print` in `paste`. Also it is good practice to pass data as an argument in the function.

```
Customer_Reporting <- function(data, Customer_ID) {
  x <- data$Age[data$Customer_ID == Customer_ID]
  paste("Customer's age is ",x)
}

Customer_Reporting(customer_information, 1251)
```

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for that! the result pastes 3 times
> Customer_Reporting(customer_information, 1251)
[1] "Customer's age is 20" "Customer's age is 20" "Customer's age is 20"

is there a way to make it only print once?

Comment: So it means you have 3 rows with same `Customer_ID`. We can use `unique`. Try `paste("Customer's age is ",unique(x))`.